Finite dimensionality of Galois cohomology
Let $K_S$ denote the maximal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, unramified outside a finite set of primes $S$, and let $G_S$ denote the Galois group of $K_S/\mathbb{Q}$.
It is known that for any finitely generated $G_S$-module $M$ over a finite field, $H^i(G_S, M)$ is finite dimensional. Is the same true when $M$ is replaced by a finite dimensional $G_S$ representation over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Yes, it's true for any profinite group satisfying (Fin p), cf. Prop. 2.1. in https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/refs/BKintro.pdf.

Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Appendix B of Rubin's book "Euler Systems" is a good reference for this.
